# Display data from mysql/phpmyadmin on html page

Tags: php, html

I'm a beginner in `PHP`.
I have tried to put PHP in HTML file in order to call data from my database called test and the table called myemployee.
I tried all the recommendation from other forum but I still did not get the display in table, instead, the code was displayed.
Following my code. Is there something wrong in my code?

Even if I put in PHP file and then, call from HTML file like this `<?php include ('test.php')?>` it still didn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link href="style/index-layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="style/homepage-layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>

<!--right-->
<div id="body">
<div id="left">

<br /><br />
<P ><B><h3>Progress</h3></FONT></B></P>

</div></div>
<?php
      $username = "root";
      $password = "";
      $host = "localhost";

      $connector = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password)
          or die("Unable to connect");
        echo "Connections are made successfully::";
      $selected = mysql_select_db("test", $connector)
        or die("Unable to connect");

      //execute the SQL query and return records
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myemployee");
      ?>
<table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Employee_id</th>
          <th>Employee_Name</th>
          <th>Employee_dob</th>
          <th>Employee_Adress</th>
          <th>Employee_dept</th>
          <th>Employee_salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
          while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
            echo "$row";
            echo
            "<tr>
              <td>{$row['employee_id']}</td>
              <td>{$row['employee_name']}</td>
              <td>{$row['employee_dob']}</td>
              <td>{$row['employee_addr']}</td>
              <td>{$row['employee_dept']}</td>
              <td>{$row['employee_sal']}</td> 
            </tr>";
          }
        ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
     <?php mysql_close($connector); ?>
<br/><br/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note: PHP MySQL is now being deprecated in favour of MySQLi functions.

Answer (score 3):

No need to call it to an html file. You can put the entire code in a .php file and run the php file.
i just checke3d your code and i put it in a php file and made some changes. It worked perfectly(without the styles obviously).
here is the code:

```
<?php
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $host = "localhost";
 $connector = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)
    or die("Unable to connect");
 $selected = mysql_select_db("sample", $connector)
    or die("Unable to connect");
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link href="style/index-layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="style/homepage-layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
    <!--right-->
    <div id="body">
        <div id="left">
        </div></div>
    <?php
    //execute the SQL query and return records
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alte_brand");
    ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Employee_id</th>
                <th>Employee_Name</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo
                "<tr>
          <td>{$row['bid']}</td>
          <td>{$row['bname']}</td>
        </tr>";
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
 </body>
 </html>
<?php mysql_close($connector); ?>
```

Comment: thanks.! its working.
but, let say i have this .html with proper layout, is it possible to display the table of data?
thanks again

Comment: @AnimAnwar the problem is php tags won't work in an html page. As far as i have worked in php. I have never used an html page with php tags. Just use a normal php page. In the browser no will know whether the page is a php/html untill the .php file type is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Check your file extensions. PHP (by default) can only run in files with .php as the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this directive to .htaccess file.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Comment: It should be there, yes. Be sure to have it enabled in your webserver. For apache see http://tildemark.com/enable-htaccess-on-apache/