# Wordpress Ninja Forms view submitted data

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin, ninja-forms

I'm using the NinjaForm plugin on my Wordpress site, which is working well but we're looking to create a custom .php page to output some of the submitted data.

Our current file is

```
<?php
 $username = "SQLuser";
 $password = "SQLpass";
 $host = "localhost";
 $connector = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)
    or die("Unable to connect");
 $selected = mysql_select_db("wordpress", $connector)
    or die("Unable to connect");
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
    <title>Report</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <!--right-->
    <?php
    //execute the SQL query and return records
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE Meta_Key LIKE '%field%'");
    ?>
    <table>
        <thead>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo
                "<tr>
          <td>{$row['post_id']}</td>
          <td>{$row['meta_key']}</td>
          <td>{$row['meta_value']}</td>
        </tr>";
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>


 </body>
 </html>
<?php mysql_close($connector); ?>
```

Mostly butchered from [Display data from mysql/phpmyadmin on html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27014042/display-data-from-mysql-phpmyadmin-on-html-page)  but this is displaying data in one long list like this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xlNu.png)

Our aim is to get this data in a table with the headers for for each field

e.g.

**_field_5** = Name,

**_field_8** = Food,

**_field_6** = Can attend

The DB format is like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrbfI.png), so the data isn't kept in separate columns in the first place, so hopefully we're able to rearrange this using php.

Any advice?

Comment: Post a link to the actual page, then we can see what the output is. This'll make it easier to help you.

Comment: Any chance you could accept my answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So, first a couple of things to note relating to best / safest practice in WP.

1. Don't create 'custom' pages. Create a custom template then add your php to that. Now create a page in WP, and assign it the relevant page template. This way you can make use of WordPress properly.
2. Use the [WP functions for querying the database](https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query) rather than querying the db directly via PHP

   ```
   <?php

   $querystr = "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE Meta_Key LIKE '%field%";

   $output = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

   ?>
   ```

Now, with that in mind you need to construct the page accordingly. Without full access to your current results page I can only vaguely guess at how to format your markup. But, something like this should get you most of the way:

```
<table>
    <thead>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        if($output){
        foreach ($output as $row){
            echo
            "<tr>
      <td>{$row['post_id']}</td>
      <td>{$row['meta_key']}</td>
      <td>{$row['meta_value']}</td>
    </tr>";
         }
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```